# Bootstrap V4.5 Carousel not working on a hosting server but works on Xampp

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

The bootstrap carousel is not working when I try to use it on a hosting server but it works on local hosting service(Xampp).
Tried uninstalling every files and reinstalling them from the FTP and it still doesn't work.

The carousel section.

```
<div id="client_reviews" class="carousel slide reveal" data-ride="carousel">
 
        <ol class="carousel-indicators ">
            <li data-target="#client_reviews" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#client_reviews" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#client_reviews" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#client_reviews" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
 
        <div class="carousel-inner" >
            <div class="carousel-item active p-5" align="center">
                <div class=" p-5 mb-5 border border-primary rounded container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="display: flex !important; align-items:stretch !important;" >
                        <div class="d-none d-md-none d-lg-block" style="float: left; width:auto; min-height:100%; padding-top: 45px;">
                            <img src="lib/content_images/about_us_images/about_us_card_img_9.png" style="width: inherit; height: inherit;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-5" style=" width:800px; height: auto;">
                            <p style="color:#000; font-family: Roboto, 'Roboto Black', 'Roboto Light', 'Roboto Medium', 'Roboto Thin', 'Space Grotesk', 'Space Grotesk Light', 'Space Grotesk Medium', 'Space Grotesk SemiBold'; font-size:20px; " align="left">I would like to say that this experience was great. The team was very professional and answered all our questions and was committed to completing our project on time. We are happy to have worked with dsgnr. and would hire them again and would recommend them to anyone else looking for a designer and developer. They know their stuff!
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pl-4 pb-5 justify-content-start align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-3 p-2" align="right"><div style="width:70px; height: 70px; background-color: antiquewhite; border-radius:100%; border: solid 1px #000; "><img src="lib/content_images/about_us_images/about_us_card_img_7.png" style=" width: inherit; height: inherit;"></div></div>
                        <div class="col-9" align="left"><h3>Milton Austin</h3><br />
                        Product Manager, Slack</div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item p-5" align="center">
                <div class=" p-5 mb-5 border border-primary rounded container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="display: flex !important; align-items:stretch !important;" >
                        <div class="d-none d-md-none d-lg-block" style="float: left; width:auto; min-height:100%; padding-top: 45px;">
                            <img src="lib/content_images/about_us_images/about_us_card_img_9.png" style="width: inherit; height: inherit;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-5" style=" width:800px; height: auto;">
                            <p style="color:#000; font-family: Roboto, 'Roboto Black', 'Roboto Light', 'Roboto Medium', 'Roboto Thin', 'Space Grotesk', 'Space Grotesk Light', 'Space Grotesk Medium', 'Space Grotesk SemiBold'; font-size:20px; " align="left">Great work ethic and very reliable! Brooklyn was our logo designer. She walked us through many iterations and guided us on all aspects of the process. Very professional, will use them again soon!”
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pl-4 pb-5 justify-content-start align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-3 p-2" align="right"><div style="width:70px; height: 70px; background-color: antiquewhite; border-radius:100%; border: solid 1px #000; "><img src="lib/content_images/about_us_images/about_us_card_img_8.png" style=" width: inherit; height: inherit;"></div></div>
                        <div class="col-9" align="left"><h3>Jane Cooper</h3><br />
                        Co-founder, Catco.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>      
            <div class="carousel-item p-5" align="center">
                <div class=" p-5 mb-5 border border-primary rounded container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="display: flex !important; align-items:stretch !important;" >
                        <div class="d-none d-md-none d-lg-block" style="float: left; width:auto; min-height:100%; padding-top: 45px;">
                            <img src="lib/content_images/about_us_images/about_us_card_img_9.png" style="width: inherit; height: inherit;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-5" style=" width:800px; height: auto;">
                            <p style="color:#000; font-family: Roboto, 'Roboto Black', 'Roboto Light', 'Roboto Medium', 'Roboto Thin', 'Space Grotesk', 'Space Grotesk Light', 'Space Grotesk Medium', 'Space Grotesk SemiBold'; font-size:20px; " align="left">I would like to say that this experience was great. The team was very professional and answered all our questions and was committed to completing our project on time. We are happy to have worked with dsgnr. and would hire them again and would recommend them to anyone else looking for a designer and developer. They know their stuff!
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pl-4 pb-5 justify-content-start align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-3 p-2" align="right"><div style="width:70px; height: 70px; background-color: antiquewhite; border-radius:100%; border: solid 1px #000; "><img src="lib/content_images/about_us_images/about_us_card_img_7.png" style=" width: inherit; height: inherit;"></div></div>
                        <div class="col-9" align="left"><h3>Milton Austin</h3><br />
                        Product Manager, Slack</div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item p-5" align="center">
                <div class=" mb-5 p-5 border border-primary rounded container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="display: flex !important; align-items:stretch !important;" >
                        <div class="d-none d-md-none d-lg-block" style="float: left; width:auto; min-height:100%; padding-top: 45px;">
                            <img src="lib/content_images/about_us_images/about_us_card_img_9.png" style="width: inherit; height: inherit;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-5" style=" width:800px; height: auto;">
                            <p style="color:#000; font-family: Roboto, 'Roboto Black', 'Roboto Light', 'Roboto Medium', 'Roboto Thin', 'Space Grotesk', 'Space Grotesk Light', 'Space Grotesk Medium', 'Space Grotesk SemiBold'; font-size:20px; " align="left">Great work ethic and very reliable! Brooklyn was our logo designer. She walked us through many iterations and guided us on all aspects of the process. Very professional, will use them again soon!”
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pl-4 pb-5 justify-content-start align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-3 p-2" align="right"><div style="width:70px; height: 70px; background-color: antiquewhite; border-radius:100%; border: solid 1px #000; "><img src="lib/content_images/about_us_images/about_us_card_img_8.png" style=" width: inherit; height: inherit;"></div></div>
                        <div class="col-9" align="left"><h3>Jane Cooper</h3><br />
                        Co-founder, Catco.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>  
 
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#client_reviews" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#client_reviews" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The bootstrap links

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
<script src="lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="lib/js/functions.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I tried reinstalling the files on FTP. I tried changing the local file links. I tried using a different browser.

Comment: What does the browser console have to say? Any 404 or other HTTP errors for relevant script files or stylesheets? Any other script errors?

Comment: Oh, there were none. It turned to be just local file issues. I fixed it by linking the bootstrap through CDNs instead of linking through local files. Thanks for the reply tho!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be just some problems with the local files that I have on the server. I fixed it by just linking Bootstrap 4.5.3 through CDNs instead of through local files.